# "The type or namespace name 'XmlSerializer' could not be found" error when System.Xml.dll is referenced

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, xmlserializer

I've already wasted a few hours on this one:

```
XmlSerializer serializer;
```

YES, the `using` is there, the reference is there, I made the entire solution in VS2010 using .NET 4.0 so it's not any of those things. If I go in Object Explorer I can find the `XmlSerializer` class I want in the correct namespace but if I try typing the above line in to my code file and compiling I get the dreaded

> The type or namespace name 'XmlSerializer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

warning of death. I don't get it on IntelliSense either. All other threads/websites I've looked on have come up blank or with one of the solutions I've already ruled out. What am I missing?
Cheers

Comment: Just to be sure, the using is for "System.Xml.Serialization" and you have a reference to System.Xml?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Do you build a Silverlight app?
Silverlight has `XmlSerializer` [defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=VS.95).aspx) inside `System.Xml.Serialization.dll` assembly which is not referenced by default.
This often leads to confusion because other framework versions have it defined in `System.Xml.dll`.

**You need to add `System.Xml.Serialization.dll` to project references to wire it up.**

Comment: Please see my edit, I was confused because the thread I used as reference had wrong answer marked correct.

Comment: cheers. that fixed it. Its weird how when i clicked 'add to references' in object explorer it said I already had it referenced. I always seem to rake-in-the-face myself on trivial things like this! :-)

Comment: @Ciemnl I wouldn't beat yourself up too hard on this, I've had similar situations before on the same sort of error, that was near impossible for me to track down by myself. Yeah it sucks, but rake-in-face not so much.

Comment: Same on Windows Phone 7 but without .dll at the end

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had this exact same problem and your tip fixed it.  Up-voted.

Comment: I ended up having to go to the framework directory and selecting the file itself as the Add Reference dialog somehow didn't link or pull the correct version for .net 4.6.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Go to `Object Explorer`, select `XmlSerializer` and choose copy. Then, paste into code

This helped me with some weird reason (no there wasn't a typo or anything like that).